# ASP.NET Core Web API Docker missing msacm32.dll NAudio

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile, naudio

I wrote a service that uses NAudio(installed through NuGet) and I put it in a docker container.
However, when I send the request to the API I get the following error:

`System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'Msacm32.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)'`

I used Docker support for auto generating the docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base 
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 80 
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build 
WORKDIR /src 
COPY ["TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj", "TestAPI/"] 
RUN dotnet restore "TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj" 
COPY . . 
WORKDIR "/src/TestAPI" 
RUN dotnet build "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final 
WORKDIR /app COPY --from=publish /app/publish . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestAPI.dll"]
```

Do I need to add something in the Docker file for this to run successfully or do I need to add the NAudio library to the project in a different way?

Thanks

I tried changing the .NET version in the Docker file but I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that NAudio is supported on Linux? On the Github repository I only see comments on various minimal Windows versions. It might be that Linux is not supported due to the usage of native Windows libraries.

Comment: @Flurin Docker is set to Windows containers. Thanks for help

Comment: What also might be is that you need a windows core container image to run it instead of the nano server image that the 6.0 tag reffers to. you could try the tag "6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022"

Answer (score 0):

NAudio contains a large number of interop wrappers for Windows APIs. To use them you need to be running on a version of Windows that includes those APIs. I suspect that the containerized Windows base image does not include multimedia APIs. The missing msacm32.dll is the DLL you use to access codecs, so even if it is there, you would also need the codec that it is trying to use (perhaps MP3) on the container image.

Alternative solutions for codecs include

- fully managed codecs (NAudio has some such as G.711, and there is also NLayer for fully managed MP3 decoding)
- trying the newer Media Foundation APIs (although they may also not be present on your Windows container image)
- bundling a tool like FFMPEG into your container and calling out to that for codec conversion